# How do I change the format of the table of figures in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I can see how to make minor changes to the formatting (font, etc) but not the general layout. I need to follow a format so that I have

1. The number (Just "6", not "Figure 6")
2. A tab/gap
3. The caption
4. Leader dots ending well before the page number
5. A gap (fixed size, not aligning)
6. The page number

Is this possible?

Comment: I trust you are aware of the field documentation? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-toc-table-of-contents-field-HP005186201.aspx

Answer (score 4):

I tried and came up with the following screenshot. Is this what you want to do?

[List of Figures in Wod 2010 http://muratarpat.com/word/word_list_of_figures.jpg](http://muratarpat.com/word/word_list_of_figures.jpg)

Comment: That looks great! Can you post how you got it? (I still need to read the link in the comment above, which may explain it some.) I'm not a heavy Word user and didn't see how I could use more than the basic configuration options.

Comment: @ Mike Graham - which one looks great, first or second list? (there is a slight difference in formatting the leading dots)

Comment: @MuratArpat, The second looks better. What I really want is a fixed-width gap (non-aligning) after the figure caption, but I think I could really work with either of these.

Comment: Can you figure out how it is done with a sample word document, or do you prefer a tutorial doc with screenshots?

Comment: @MuratArpat, whatever you provide, it would be nice if anyone finding this answer could see it.

Comment: OK, I will prepare a doc with screenshots, and when it is ready I'll put it on my site. One thing I should mention is that the result in figure above involves a little manual input which should be done after the table of figures is finalized, as I could not do everything automatically.

Comment: Good Job Murat. Really looking forward to this!

Comment: @MuratArpat, You mean you had to physically type something for every entry?

Comment: @Mike Graham, you do not have to type but press TAB key in each entry. I know this is not efficient for long tables, but I could not have word do this automatically, even though I setup tab stops when customizing Table of Figures.

I put the tut doc on my site with the following address, I hope it helps to any one with this kind of problem.

http://muratarpat.com/word/tof_tut.docx